# Which C# project should I use for a certain requirement?

Tags: c#

I've got a request from a stakeholder who wants us to automate the following procedure.

1. Go to the CMS website (In-house application)
2. Take a picture of the report.
3. Send an email to stakeholders with the reports attached.

Note: This procedure must be repeated on a daily basis.

And I'm not sure which project to choose for the above need; at the moment, all I can think of is a Console Application, but I'm not sure much about it.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Code For Screenshot - Selenium C#

```
  public class ScreenShotRepository
{
    public static void TakeScreenShot(IWebDriver Driver, string filename, List<string> text = null)
    {
        var bytesArr = Driver.TakeScreenshot(new VerticalCombineDecorator(new ScreenshotMaker()));
        var screenshotImage = (System.Drawing.Image)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(bytesArr));

        WriteToPDF(new List<System.Drawing.Image>() { screenshotImage }, filename, text);
    }

    public static void WriteToPDF(List<System.Drawing.Image> screenshots, string filename, List<string> text)
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        var document = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, screenshots[0].Width, screenshots[0].Height), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        document.Open();

        var content = writer.DirectContent;
        var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        for (int i = 0; i < screenshots.Count; i++)
        {
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(screenshots[i], screenshots[i].RawFormat);

            document.Add(image);

            WriteText(content, font, text);

            if (i + 1 != screenshots.Count)
                document.NewPage();
        }
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static void WriteText(PdfContentByte content, BaseFont font, List<string> text)
    {
        content.BeginText();
        content.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN);
        content.SetFontAndSize(font, 40);

        for (int j = 0; j < text.Count; j++)
            content.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, text[j].ToString(), 50, 50 + 50 * j, 0);

        content.EndText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is also full of `IDisposable` objects that you aren't disposing. Your process will run out of handles very quickly and crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* make this a Windows Service, because of the daily call requirement.

However, the simplest way is indeed a console application that you schedule to run using your operating systems task scheduler.

And as far as the requirements go, why can't the reporting system *output* a PDF? Taking a screenshot of another software is already a really makeshift solution if it were third-party, taking screenshots of your own reporting software just says whoever programs the inhouse CMS system is... not up to the task if there is a requirement to automate it outside of their domain.

Comment: @QA_A - I think the approach to use an app to take a image of another app is just plain ludicrous. It's the least useful file format for a report and it's exceedingly fragile.

Comment: Actually - Report is showing as Page in CMS - so need to take that Page data screenshot and then send it to stakeholder daily

Comment: @QA_A - You're better off scraping the page and producing a PDF. Anything is better than hoping you can get a screenshot.

Comment: Actually - I have code to capture the screenshot as PDF and even have code for sending an email with Selenium webdriver - But with the above requirement not sure which project would be feasible

Comment: @QA_A - Don't take screenshots. That's what I think is the worst part about your solution.